# How to create a Main Menu that links to another view? (When developing iPhone Apps)

Tags: iphone, sdk, view

I'm a newbie programmer and I have played around with the SDK for a while. How do you create a homepage that has a button that will bring you to another view (the content of the app)??? If you know can you list the steps in order or link a tutorial site (It woul be awesome if the steps had code with it I needed). Thanks!

Comment: Are you making a navigation-based app (i.e. using `UINavigationController`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend getting a good book on iPhone programming. What you want to do is set up a UINavigationController, add the button to the first view, set the action of the button's touchUpInside to call the showContent method. Then implement the showContent method to push the Content view controller.

```
- (IBAction) showContent{
    ContentViewController *myContentController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    myContentController.title = @"Content";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myContentController animated:YES];
    [myContentController release];
}
```

Have a read up on the documentation for pushViewController and UINavigationControllers, then follow [this tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/).

Comment: No worries, there are quite a few tutorials on the topic. My recommendation is that when you get taught something in a tutorial, read up in the documentation about a couple of the things that you learned about. Once you understand how to use the documentation, the world is your oyster.

Comment: How can you do it without having cells and stuff?

Comment: If you read my post it explains roughly what to do. Try working through that step by step. If you get stuck, post a new question. If you try and work through a good book, you will be amazed at how quickly things progress. 'Beginning iPhone Development' is a good start.

Comment: Here is another simple tutorial, work through it and try and merge it with what you have already. The code above might also be helpful.

http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-helloworld